# Parent and child model interaction

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

is it possible set something like wpf window owner in caliburn.micro ?

I have PARENT VIEW MODEL, from this model I open CHILD SCREEN {VIEW MODEL} with this method:

```
    public IEnumerable<IResult> Open()
    {

        yield return new ShowWindow("ChatScreen")
            .InitializeWith(_service
            .DetailData(Account, _selectedFriend.Value.Nick),
            AvatarImage);
    }
```

This method create a new WPF WINDOW - CHILD SCREEN and initialize CHILD VIEW MODEL with some variables.

I would like set something like this CHILD_SCREEN.PARENT = PARENT_VIEW_MODEL.

I would like achieve if I close PARENT VIEW MODEL that it close also all CHILD MODELS.

Also it exist way how can I check if screen, in my situation WPF window, is active/inactive from MAIN VIEW MODEL?

Comment: The "Master\slave" terminology is deprecated in favour of "Parent\child" these days.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write the infrastructure for this.  I'm assuming ShowWindow is using Caliburn.Micro's WindowManager to display the window?  In which case, you'll need to maintain a reference to each window that is open.  Is this parent/child relationship requirement just for the purpose of closing all children when the parent is closed?  One option would be to implement your own Conductor type which maintains a list of open windows, and your own IScreen/Screen types which maintain parent/child relationship state.